Gamma distribution glm standardisation
I want to model biomarkers which seem to have two distributions. I want to model the change in biomarker at two visits three years apart. However, I am trying to do this with a glm and a gamma distribution in R. I have standardised the biomarker change so I can compare all the biomarkers. However it says that it can't take negative values? Can anyone advise what methods I can use to be able to standardise and still use these values, please?
Thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hi @Steph, welcome to CV. "I have standardised the biomarker change so I can compare all the biomarkers." - note that a Gamma can only take positive values, so a Gamma won't be appropriate. I think you need to add more detail to your question to describe your study and objectives more :)

Hi. am doing association analyses with biomarkers associated with dementia such ab42, ab40, and ab4240. While the ab42 and ab40 are approximately normally distributed the ab4240 looks like it has two distributions when I check the histogram. I always standardise my variables so that I can compare the different biomarkers on the same scale. I read online that if you standardise and you add a number eg 1, it can still be interpreted on standard deviation scale. I am looking at change in biomarker across two time points and the taking the standard deviation.
